# How to solve XGBoost error for traceback and unknown objective function?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgbclassifier

I was trying to build an XGBoost Binary Classification model. I set up my training and test data and performed the following action to fit the data into the model.

```
clf_xgb = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective = 'binary: logistic', missing = None, seed = 42)
clf_xgb.fit(X_train,
            y_train,
            eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)],
            eval_metric = 'aucpr',
            early_stopping_rounds=10,
            verbose = True
            )
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-2a6f36907545> in <module>
----> 1 clf_xgb.fit(X_train, 
      2             y_train,
      3             eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)],
      4             eval_metric = 'aucpr',
      5             early_stopping_rounds=10,

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    434         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    435             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 436         return f(**kwargs)
    437 
    438     return inner_f

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
   1174         )
   1175 
-> 1176         self._Booster = train(
   1177             params,
   1178             train_dmatrix,

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, xgb_model, callbacks)
    187     Booster : a trained booster model
    188     """
--> 189     bst = _train_internal(params, dtrain,
    190                           num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
    191                           evals=evals,

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks, evals_result, maximize, verbose_eval, early_stopping_rounds)
     74             show_stdv=False, cvfolds=None)
     75 
---> 76     bst = callbacks.before_training(bst)
     77 
     78     for i in range(start_iteration, num_boost_round):

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\callback.py in before_training(self, model)
    374         '''Function called before training.'''
    375         for c in self.callbacks:
--> 376             model = c.before_training(model=model)
    377             msg = 'before_training should return the model'
    378             if self.is_cv:

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\callback.py in before_training(self, model)
    513 
    514     def before_training(self, model):
--> 515         self.starting_round = model.num_boosted_rounds()
    516         return model
    517 

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in num_boosted_rounds(self)
   2005         rounds = ctypes.c_int()
   2006         assert self.handle is not None
-> 2007         _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterBoostedRounds(self.handle, ctypes.byref(rounds)))
   2008         return rounds.value
   2009 

D:\Softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _check_call(ret)
    208     """
    209     if ret != 0:
--> 210         raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
    211 
    212 

XGBoostError: [12:05:23] C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.4.0\src\objective\objective.cc:26: Unknown objective function: `binary: logistic`
Objective candidate: survival:aft
Objective candidate: binary:hinge
Objective candidate: multi:softmax
Objective candidate: multi:softprob
Objective candidate: rank:pairwise
Objective candidate: rank:ndcg
Objective candidate: rank:map
Objective candidate: count:poisson
Objective candidate: survival:cox
Objective candidate: reg:gamma
Objective candidate: reg:tweedie
Objective candidate: reg:squarederror
Objective candidate: reg:squaredlogerror
Objective candidate: reg:logistic
Objective candidate: reg:pseudohubererror
Objective candidate: binary:logistic
Objective candidate: binary:logitraw
Objective candidate: reg:linear
```

Can anyone please explain what is going on here. How do I fix this error?
I am using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3 and using the latest XGB library version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove space from `'binary:logistic'` and it should work. According to this [this](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) documentation there is no space in between.